# Looking for references on 複合格助詞

Tags: particles, syntax

I am currently doing research on automatic case frame (格フレーム) acquisition and its applications. A case frame describes the syntactic structure of a predicate by providing a canonical representation of its syntactic structure (also known as 文型).
Traditionally, 文型 contain only non-complex case-marker (e.g. が, を, に, で), however, for some applications in computational linguistics, we are also interested in complex case-markers (複合格助詞) such as 〜として, 〜に関して, 〜をめぐって, 〜とともに, and so on.

Do you know of any comprehensive study on 複合格助詞?
Is there a list of most frequent 複合格助詞?

At the moment, the best I have is the list given in 『現代日本語文法　第３部格と構文』 but it lacks some common 複合格助詞 (e.g. をめぐって).

[EDIT] Thanks to @snailboat I also got the list proposed by Samuel Martin in *Reference Grammar of Japanese* (about 200 phrasal postpositions). As the author noted:

> (...) it is difficult to give clear criteria for what is, and what is not, a
>   phrasal postposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel Martin calls these **phrasal postpositions** in his 1975 *Reference Grammar of Japanese*.  Starting on page 577 he produces a list of over 200 of these, giving literary and modern forms where applicable, marking whether は or も can be inserted between the elements, whether a polite version is available (as in につきまして for について), and so on.  Although you're unlikely to be satisfied that this list is complete, it could make a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for the pointer! I checked on Google Books but unfortunately pages 577-- are not available. I am gonna have to wait a little bit 'til I can go to my university's library... or is the list available elsewhere?

Comment: btw 寺村秀夫 (in シンタクスと意味) uses the term 「格助詞句」. which seems to match Martin's "phrasal postposition"...

Answer (score 0):

MUST1 project annotates compound functional expressions (CFE) in a newswire corpus.
Although it requires the non-free 毎日新聞(1995年版CD-ROM) corpus, one can extract CFE from the `*.xml` files located in `MUST-dist-1.0/core`.

All these CFE do not correspond to 複合格助詞, yet the resource is worth a look.

Project home page: http://nlp.iit.tsukuba.ac.jp/must/